# why the user cannot open a text file which is read-only?

Tags: command-line, permissions

> At first I wrote some wrong information by mistake, sorry. Please read the following again, because I have made some serious changes. I have changed a screenshot, and also have added a screenshot.

I set the permission for a plain text document (`doc2`) as `read-only` for a user `ripon`  (`doc2` is a file in the folder `monir`). To do this I used the following command:-

```
sudo setfacl -R -m "g:ripon:r--" /home/london/monir
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 in Oracle VM VirtualBox. I am the administrator, and I created some user accounts using Terminal. `ripon` is one of the users.

When I log off from my administrator account and log on as `ripon`, I should be able to open the text file `doc2` and read what is written inside. But surprisingly, I cannot even open the file!

**The file is `read-only` for `ripon`, so why is it **Not** possible for `ripon` to open and read the text file?**

[When I log in as `monir` , I can open, read and write the file `doc2`. Because I gave 'monir' full permission (rwx) for the file using terminal]

[image: Screenshot 1: ripon cannot open the text file]

[image]

[image: user <code>monir</code> can open and read the file <code>doc2</code>]

Comment: can you try $sudo setfacl -R -m "g:ripon:r--" /home/london/monir/doc2 and check if it making any changes

Comment: tried... nothing changed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this command. Hope this will solve the issue.

```
setfacl -R -m u:ripon:r-x /home/london/monir/doc2
```

Comment: what is the command to see what permissions ripon has over this directory `/home/london/monir/` ?

Comment: You can use `getfacl` to view the ACL

Comment: i changed the command u gave to `setfacl -R -m u:ripon:r-x /home/london/monir/` and now the files CAN be opened and read by ripon. That means:-- `i have to give execute (x) permission as well to ripon to  open the text file by him` . Thank you so much :)  By the way, i thought `execute` only applies to files which are `.exe` or something like it.

Comment: You don't need to give `x` permission in order to read a file, Just `r` will be enough. But for entering to the directory `/home/london/monir/` you need `x` permission. I don't know if it possible to change the permission of the  file only, I mean without effecting the directory in which the file is. If it possible you can remove the `x` from the command and give only `r` permission.

Comment: without giving `x` permission to the directory (using `setfacl -R -m`) , the text files are not openable by ripon. Why is that?